# isse :vue js high chart lollipop chart X axis label show overlapped

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I created a lollipop chart in vue js using the high chart library. But the problem is the X axis label is overlapping and not showing correctly. Labels are coming dynamically from the csv file in one of the column. See attached example and please  let us know if anyone has any solution.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/912uS.png).aslo display error in browser console such as " attribute transform expected number "translate(Nan,0)"

i try to solve xAxis label display properly for this i try change style,min and max value but still not solve so i expect display label correctly.

Comment: Could you please provide your chart config or reproduce the issue in the online demo? You can start with this simplified example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/silly-bhaskara-k64zry

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hello @magdalena i can not provide any chart configuration because of  i can not share code if you want to help me then come on skype i need solution urgently my skype id is https://join.skype.com/invite/XW0q2MLIhNcY.

Comment: in my code i use like this

Comment: in my code i use like this dataLabels:{ x:function() { return -(this.plotX+80)    }  } this code give error in console such as error: "<g> attribute transform : expected number translate(NaN,0)" .how solve this error.when i remove this code label not display in front of  chart horizontal line its display messed up.i use lolipop chart

Comment: SO support can be provided only on the platform. If you are an advantage user you can contact us via chat: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/support/ ; Getting back to the code, thank you for providing the snippet. The `dataLabels.x` must be provided as a number not a function. If you want to format dataLabels using some conditionals, you can use `dataLabels.formatter` callback: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.formatter